# Hibernate Bug closed, but I can sill reproduce it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate bug [HHH-7478](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7478) has been marked closed by the hibernate community and has been resolved since 4.2.1. I'm currently in 4.2.5 and when I try to replicate the same use case, as mentioned on the attached ticket. I can reproduce the bug.

I could not register on Hibernate site to comment on the bug as not fixed yet. Before I do that, I wanted to confirm if I'm doing anything wrong;

[Their test case](https://github.com/cameronbraid/hibernate-envers-cme/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/Main.java)

My class;

```
public class OOPostUpdateEventListener implements PostUpdateEventListener, EnversListener {

  public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

    ...do something

      System.out.println(" Registering BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess ");
      event.getSession().getActionQueue().registerProcess(new BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess() {
        @Override
        public void doBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImplementor session) {
          System.out.println("BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess");
        }
      });

      System.out.println(" Registering AfterTransactionCompletionProcess ");
      event.getSession().getActionQueue().registerProcess(new AfterTransactionCompletionProcess() {

        @Override
        public void doAfterTransactionCompletion(boolean success, SessionImplementor session) {
          System.out.println("AfterTransactionCompletionProcess");
        }
     });
  }

}
```

The logs look something like this;

```
-- Registering BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess
-- Registering AfterTransactionCompletionProcess 
-- Exception; 
    ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification() line: 819    
    ArrayList$Itr.next() line: 791  
    ActionQueue.executeActions(List) line: 368  
    ActionQueue.executeActions() line: 287  
    DefaultFlushEventListener(AbstractFlushingEventListener).performExecutions(EventSource) line: 339   
    DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(FlushEvent) line: 52  
    SessionImpl.flush() line: 1234  
    SessionImpl.managedFlush() line: 404    
    JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit() line: 101 
    JdbcTransaction(AbstractTransactionImpl).commit() line: 175 
    HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 554    
    HibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) line: 755   
    HibernateTransactionManager(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager).commit(TransactionStatus) line: 724 
    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) line: 475                                    TransactionInterceptor(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) line: 270  
    TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 94    
-- AfterTransactionCompletionProcess
```

Is there something wrong with what I've done? Or is the bug not fixed ?

**Edit:** The bug is for PostInsert, and my code pertains to PostUpdate